# Codeigniter ignore email config

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, codeigniter-2

I'm using the framework codeigniter. I don't understand the email library behaviour.
I use a configuration for send email, but even putting a fake/wrong configuration I can send emails!

For example, I create de file email.php in the folder config and I put:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'fakepassword';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
```

Then I do:

```
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library("email");
        $CI->email->from( app_recover_pass_from, app_recover_pass_from_name);
        $CI->email->to($email);
        $CI->email->subject( app_recover_pass_subject );
        $CI->email->message(sprintf(app_recover_pass_message,$newPassword));
        if ( ! $CI->email->send())
```

And I receive the email!!! The email was sent.

Even if I create a configuration and set into the load library method I can send emails with a wrong/fake configuration, like another entity was sending the emails.

```
$array['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$array['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$array['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$array['smtp_pass'] = 'fakepassword';
$array['smtp_port'] = '465';

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library("email",$array);
...
```

I don't understand. I just want send email throw my Gmail, but I can't because Email library don't take my configuration and I don't understand which default configuration is taken (I suppose that codeingniter default configuration)

Comment: create one file email.php in config folder put all your configuration into that file codeigniter automatically take that config

Answer (score 0):

After you have loaded the email class, you should initialize it, with the configuration options. Like this;

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config = array(
    // config options
);
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Here's a URL to the user guide, for your reference;
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: What do you get if you print the debugger? $this->email->print_debugger()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried autoloading the email configuration?

In `application/config/autoload.php`, look for `$autoload['config']` and add email to the array (CI v2.1.x)

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Config files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['config'] = array('config1', 'config2');
|
| NOTE: This item is intended for use ONLY if you have created custom
| config files.  Otherwise, leave it blank.
|
*/

$autoload['config'] = array('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was extending the email class, it ignores the email.php config and sends it using the default server email configuration. If you are extending you will need to add the __construct from the original Email.php library into your extended library

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email
{

    function __construct($config = array())
    {
        if (count($config) > 0)
        {
            $this->initialize($config);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_smtp_auth = ($this->smtp_user == '' AND $this->smtp_pass == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;
            $this->_safe_mode = ((boolean)@ini_get("safe_mode") === FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }

        log_message('debug', "Email Class Initialized");
    }
}
```